# Bash: Assign many variables in one operation

Tags: bash

I have a file like

```
line1 word1 word2 word4 etc..
line2 word1 word2 word4 etc..
```

I know I can extract words with `cut -d ' ' -fx` command but I want to extract and assign many words in one operation.

```
while read line;do
  echo $line | awk '{ word1=$1; word2=$2 }'
  # usage $word1, $word2, etc.
done < $file
```

Is this possible?

#### Better example

file

```
jose  1234 2011/12/01
maria 2345 2010/04/10
```

script

```
while read line;do
  echo $line | awk '{ name=$1; counter=$2, date=$3 }'
  # usage $name, $counter, $date, etc
done < $file
```

Comment: Do you know how many words are in each line?  Do you know what is the maximum number of words in a line?  Is there some maximum number of interesting words in a line?  Would an array work better?  (In jest: _why is word2 followed by word4?_)

Comment: I need assign words to variables

Comment: Yes; you said you need to assign words to variables in the question.  How are you going to know which variables to access later?  How do you know how many words were set?  There are probably a number of ways of doing this; but some understanding of what happens next would help.  How do you plan to handle the 20th word on a line, for example?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the number of words in a line is fixed (the easy case), then:

```
while read name number date
do
    # ...use $name, $number, $date
done <<'EOF'
jose  1234 2011/12/01
maria 2345 2010/04/10
EOF
```

Note that if there are 4 or more words in the line, `$date` will get all the remaining words after the name and number.  If there are fewer than three, the `read` will work but the variables without a value (`date` or `number` or even `name`) will be empty strings.

If the number of words in a line is variable, then you probably want to use `bash` [arrays](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Arrays) with [`read`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-read):

```
while read -a array
do
    # ...process "${array[@]}"...
    echo "${array[@]}"
done <<'EOF'
one
two three
four five six
seven eight
nine
EOF
```

Answer (score 3):

It's possible using awk

```
root@server$ vars=$( awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){ print "word" i "=" $i }}' file )
root@server$ echo $vars
word1=one word2=two word3=three
root@server$ declare $vars
root@server$ echo $word1 
one
```

So the breakdown

Awk has in internal variable NF which is the number of fields in the line. So we run a quick for loop iterating over all the fields, skipping field 0 as thats the whole line. for each iteration we print out a bash variable assignment statement and capture the output into the vars variable.

we then use declare to declare the variables. If we don't use declare then we are executing some arbitary code in a file.

Hope this is usefull.